# App Engine, content type of uploaded file in blob viewer is application/octet-stream?

Tags: file-upload, blob, content-type

I uploaded images to app engine. The size of file in data store is the same to the file in my computer. But the content type in blob viewer is application/octet-stream and it can't be displayed. I checked some materials that says if I don't specify the content type, it will be stored in a default type that is application/octet-stream.
But how cloud I specify the content type? 
Thank you ~~